# Conditionally display markup formatted text based on shiny input

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I'm trying to create an Rmarkdown that displays different amounts of text based on user input into a shiny application. I've made an basic example below. There are 2 text inputs and a checkbox. If the checkbox is false only the 1st text box value is printed to the markdown. If the checkbox is true then both values are printed. I want the output for both text boxes to appear like the 1st textbox output.

Ui:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(


  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(

      textInput(inputId = "text1", 
                label =  "1st text", value = "1st text"),

      checkboxInput(inputId = "checkBox", label = "Checkbox"),

      textInput(inputId = "input2", 
                  label =  "2nd text", value = "2nd text"),

      downloadButton("download", "Download button")

    ),

    mainPanel(

      verbatimTextOutput("checkBoxValue")

    )
  )
)
```

Server:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

server <- function(input, output) {

output$checkBoxValue <- renderText(input$checkBox)


Text1Value <- reactive({input$text1})
BoxValue<- reactive(input$checkBox)
Input2Value <- reactive({input$input2})

output$download <- downloadHandler(
  filename = "Test.docx",
  content = function(file) {
    tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "TestRMD.Rmd")
    file.copy("TestRMD.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE) 


    params = list(


      Text1Value = Text1Value(),
      BoxValue = BoxValue(),
      Input2Value = Input2Value()

    )

    rmarkdown::render(
      tempReport,
      output_file = file,
      params = params,
      envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()),
      quiet = FALSE
    )
  })
}
```

Rmarkdown:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: word_document
params: 
    Text1Value: NA
    BoxValue: NA
    Input2Value: NA
---

```{r echo= FALSE, message = FALSE, include = FALSE}

library(shiny)
library(knitr)
library(latex2exp)


Text1Value<- params$Text1Value
BoxValue<- params$BoxValue
Input2Value<- params$Input2Value

```

# Value for text 1 is `r Text1Value`

```{r, echo=FALSE}
if(BoxValue == TRUE){
"Value for input 2 is `r Input2Value`"
}

```
````

Currently I can get the text from the second text output to appear conditionally, however it renders looking like R code. I want it to appear in the same format as the output for the 1st text input.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The the following in your Rmd file. You already are in a code block and don't need to have additional inline r formatting. You can use `results = 'asis'` in your block and also add the header (#) for identical formatting if you'd like:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
if(BoxValue == TRUE){
  cat("# Value for input 2 is", Input2Value)
}
```
````

Comment: Thank you that worked. How would I add more than just one line? Would I need one if statement for each line?

Comment: You can include as many lines as you'd like. If you have text you want to spread on multiple lines you can use `\n` in `cat` for newline, for example. Or you can have additional `cat` or other statements to display text (one after another). But no need for additional `if` statements, if I understand correctly.